# How to skip whole records/models when using Eloquent API Resources

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the API resources & collections from here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

It works pretty well, except I can't find a clean way to filter returned models (records). So here's what I'm doing now:

```
class MyResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        if($someCondition) {
            return [];
        }

        if(! $otherCondition) {
            return null;
        }

        return [
            'data' => [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'url' => $this->link,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Then from my api.php routes file, I call that like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/myendpoint', function(Request $request) {
    return MyResource::collection(Item::paginate()->withQueryString());
});
```

This mostly works, but my early returns still show up in the output as literal "null" values (the string "null").

I've searched and searched, from Google to Youtube to the Laravel docs and here on SO, but I can't find any mention of this.  Is there really no way to exclude certain records/models from the API output?

Of course, I could manually code this up in my controller & model, but it'd be really nice to use Laravel's built-in API resources for this.

Comment: That does not seem to be a responsibility of the resource but of the query

Comment: As the previous user mentioned, that is the controller or whoever gathers the data from the source of truth, not the Resource responsibility... The Resource responsibility is to decide how to show the data, not what data to show. You can still do what you want and you can also use some methods the Resource has to decide whether to show or not some index, but is different from showing nothing to not showing an index of the array data for each data.